# Migrate Docker multi-container app to Azure

Tags: docker-compose, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I have a Linux CentOS host running Docker Ce with multiple containers running a few multi-containers apps (webapps using docker-compose) and I would like to migrate those containers to Azure Containers serverless platform.

How can i migrate all those containers with the volumes?

Making a Azure container registry and push the containers to that registry will move the data volumes? or how is the process to migrate?

Thanks

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it work for you? If it solves your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Azure Container Instances, I used Azure WebApps for Containers.

Answer (score 0):

> Making an Azure container registry and push the containers to that
> registry will move the data volumes?

No, push the images to the Azure Container Registry just push the images, not the volume that mounts to the containers.

> How can I migrate all those containers with the volumes?

You just can use the [ACI via docker-compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) to deploy the YAML to the ACI without the local volumes. You can try to upload the files to the [Azure File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files) and mount the File share to each instance.